# Is it possible to line up list items that are of different types, i.e images and a button?

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate the google home page but I'm having trouble lining up the items in the menu in the top right?

I tried text-align but that doesn't seem to do anything.

any help with this would be greatly appriciated!

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a:link {
  color: #000;
}
#picture_menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 10px;
}
#share {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  color: #444!important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 210px;
  background-image: url("images/logo.png");
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#searchbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
}
#microphone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 405px;
  left: 625px;
  background: url('images/microphone.png') no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
#search_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #444!important;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
}
#lucky_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #444!important;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
}
#tag_text {
  background: url(images/mountains.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 140px;
}
#tag_text span {
  color: red;
}
#tag_text a:link {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  font-family: arial;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#+Adam">+Adam</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#gmail">Gmail</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#images">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2Wyc6B.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0Xtg2MN.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="button" value="Share" id="share" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6ku5ORI.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that `input` elements have no closing tag. Instead of `<input></input>`, just use `<input>` or `<input />`.

Comment: ok thank you, I'll take note of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a JSFiddle for your issue, you can find it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41618a6y/)

I also changed **li's** `display: inline` into `display: inline-block`, you can try changing the padding to get the right result..

Comment: I had to put the images in a seperate div to be able to line it up in the end. Thanks